# How do I check a byte representation to an enumeration member in python?

Tags: python

In C# I can check a byte representation to an enum number like this:

```cs
using System;

namespace HelloWorld {
    class Hello {
        public enum Types {
            NONE = 0x01,
            TRUE = 0x02,
            FALSE = 0x03,
            STRING_8 = 0x30
        };
        
        static void Main() {
            // 3 would be the byte number -> FALSE
            // 48 would be the byte number -> STRING_8
            Console.WriteLine((Types)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Types), 3));
            Console.WriteLine((Types)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Types), 48));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I replicate this in Python? I don't know what function to look for to make this work, I need this to parse binary files in Python that contain json data.

I looked up on google and found out enumeration classes do exist in Python, but couldn't find a function that fits & answers my problem.

Comment: There really is no meaning to the "byte representation of an enum" in Python. You can associate an enum instance/member with any arbitrary object. If you have `SomeEnum`, and you want to retreive the instance/member by `SomeEnum(value)`

Comment: Yeah, my original question was flawed but the answer below solves my problem.